# Single Byte XOR Cipher

Tags: decode, xor

I am supposed to decode this string: `IConIT0xdSoldit1GTJ2GTIudRkxdigidTQgMyoZMXY0KiIZdiAZJTQ/NjJ2Zzs=`

I first recognize that this is in base64 format, so i decode it to hex and get `202a27213d31752a25762b7519327619322e751931762822753420332a193176342a221976201925343f363276673b`.
Then I tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41819489/single-byte-xor-cipher-python?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) solution to decipher the text but it isn't working.
I've been stumped for days trying to figure this out. Can anyone provide me with a clue as how to proceed with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. The decrypted string has some unusual properties, and you're unlikely to be able to detect it with frequency analysis. You can narrow down the possibilities a little by considering the range that the XORed characters will end up in, but the easiest approach will be to just try them all and print the results.

> The correct XOR key is between 0x40 and 0x5f.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still stuck. I even tried using an online XOR cipher and tried all keys from 0x40 to 0x5f but still have no luck. I used the cipher at xor.pw and put in the hex value that starts `202a272...` and manually inputted hex values from 40 to 5f and didn't get anything remotely close to what I'm supposed to get which is a flag with the format `flag{....}`

Comment: That calculator may be misleading. Entering a single hex character will make it only XOR the last (!) byte of the input; the rest of the input is unchanged. Try repeating the key 47 (or more) times so that it's as long as the input.

Comment: Thanks so much. Since I knew the format of the flag, I could have XOR'd keys of the first hex digit `20` until it matched `f`

Comment: Correct. If you had mentioned that detail in the question, I would have given a more specific hint. :)